# Delphi API Hooks behave oddly

Tags: api, delphi, winapi, hook

I'm trying to implement an API Hooking mechanism.

What I have so far, is a DLL injected into other processes via a `SetWindowsHookEx` call, and some code to implement the hooks themselves.

For example, I can successfully hook `MessageBoxA` calls across multiple different applications (thats not the end goal).

What I need to do is hook some graphics functions, in particular textout functions as I need to be able to screen scrape.

Now - I'm aware which textout functions I need (`TextOutA/W`, `ExtTextOutA/W` for the application I'm trying to access), and I'm aware I need to hook `Begin/EndPaint` or `Get/ReleaseDC` to match the `DC`'s to window handles and determine if the textout is on a window I'm interested in.

My problem is that while I can hook the textout functions, messageboxes and so on without any problems what so ever, `GetDC` results in a hard crash as does `BeginPaint`.

The code is quite long, so I'll post what I'm having problems with, but I can post more if it helps.

The rough frame work is as follows;

```
function CustomBeginPaint(hWnd: HWND; var lpPaint: TPaintStruct): HDC;
begin
  UninstallHook();

  Result := BeginPaint(hWnd, lpPaint );

  InstallHook();
end;
```

Even this quite simple function fails constantly, returning zero.

I'm at a complete loss to explain whats going on, as the `hWnd` is always 1309192 despite trying this on multiple machines.

Comment: You say you get a "hard crash" when calling GetDC and BeginPaint, then you say your quoted function, that calls BeginPaint, returns zero - if it crashes, how can it return zero?  Also, what do you mean by "hard crash" - application crash, system crash, BSOD?  Which OS are you using?  Is your application 32 or 64 bit?  Are you hooking into a 32 or 64 bit process?  This feels like a difficult question to answer without a lot more information.

Comment: edit your question please and add TAG of your Delphi version. Also do you target Win64 or Win32 ?

Comment: Also, if `BeginPaint` is returning zero/null, it's because you've given it a bad HWND.  That the HWND is always the same is suspect - this shouldn't really ever be expected.  Where is `CustomBeginPaint` called?  If it is a direct hook callback, how are you setting the hook?  Can you show your forward declarations?

Comment: The unhooking und re-hooking isn't thread-safe. If the application has multiple GUI Thread (The VCL doesn't support it but you can load a DLL that has its own GUI thread) this can crash or cause interesting bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the key issue was, as Andreas Hausladen mentioned thread safety - but not due to the VCL.